# Downsampling and upsampling of a signal in Python

Tags: python, downsampling, resampling, scipy

If I want to downsample a signal in Python, is it better to use method **resample** from SciPy Signal Processing module or method **decimate** from the same module? What is the difference between these two approaches?
And my next question is: Which is the best way of upsampling a signal?

Thank you very much for replies.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Signal Processing StackExchange! So, scipy has pretty good documentation, so you can directly compare these two, and ask a question based on the documentation, maybe? That would be better then asking us to reproduce the documentation first, I think.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome!
I have already read SciPy documentation, I understand that **resample** uses the Fourier transform and **decimate** uses the antialiasing filter, but it is not clear to me what is it best practice (if there is any).

Comment: Interesting! for which purpose do you want to downsample? What's your in- and output?

Comment: I have at my disposal signals which are sampled with the frequency 100 kHz and they can be even several hours long, they take a lot of memory. Moreover, I think it is necessary to have such a high sampling frequency (in one setting the maximal frequency of the signal is 100 Hz, in other setting it is unknown, but I assume it is waaaay smaller than 50 kHz.)